# Availability Set in Availability Zone Arm Configuration

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to build out a script which deploys a vm into an availability set within an Azure availability zone.

However I keep getting the following error. I think (guessing) that it's to do with the fact the av set is not deployed to the same zone as the vm, but cannot find anywhere to set the zone on the availability set.

Error:

```
 New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 22:41:38 - Error: Code=InvalidRequestContent; Message=The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'zone' on 
object of type 'TemplateResource'. Path 'properties.template.resources[3].zone', line 217, position 17.'.
At C:\ps\test-vm-build.ps1:182 char:7
+       New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "SapTestDeploy" -ResourceGr ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

The ARM template has been uploaded to:

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/5Afn6Pip

Hoping someone has ome across this and can point me in the right direction, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-powershell-availability-zone) _may_ point you in the correct direction.

Comment: @Darrell thanks for that, but that’s not working I’m afraid, I have been through all the checks and i can’t quite put my finger on the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create an availability set:

```
New-AzAvailabilitySet `
   -Location "EastUS" `
   -Name "myAvailabilitySet" `
   -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupAvailability" `
   -Sku aligned `
   -PlatformFaultDomainCount 2 `
   -PlatformUpdateDomainCount 2
```

Create a Virtual Machine inside the availability set:

```
New-AzVm `
        -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupAvailability" `
        -Name "myVM$i" `
        -Location "East US" `
        -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" `
        -SubnetName "mySubnet" `
        -SecurityGroupName "myNetworkSecurityGroup" `
        -PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIpAddress$i" `
        -AvailabilitySetName "myAvailabilitySet" `
        -Credential $cred
```

**UPDATE** (Location/UpdateDomain/FaultDomain):

```
New-AzAvailabilitySet
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-Name] <String>
   [-Location] <String>
   [[-PlatformUpdateDomainCount] <Int32>]
   [[-PlatformFaultDomainCount] <Int32>]
   [[-Sku] <String>]
   [-ProximityPlacementGroupId <String>]
   [-Tag <Hashtable>]
   [-AsJob]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

**UPDATE**:
Powershell to move a VM to an Availability Zone:

https://github.com/kpantos/azure-automation/blob/master/powershell/change-vm-zone.ps1

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't specify an availbility zone anywhere? Although I just got this message: `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 09:19:25 - The deployment 'TestazAs' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: Virtual Machine cannot be created because both Availability Zone and Availability Set were specified. Deploying an Availability Set to an Availability 
Zone isn’t supported. (Code:BadRequest)
CorrelationId: 60b01d6d-8a96-4769-b047-e0885740f6b4`

Comment: Can we use Availability sets with Availability Zones?

Comment: Availability Zones are the next level for Availability Sets with an increased SLA from 99,95 to 99,99. You can use Azure Site Recovery to move your VM's to an Availability Zone. But yes it is possible.

Comment: thanks, can we create new VMs in an av set in an wv zone?

Comment: yes, with Site Recovery. check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/move-azure-vms-avset-azone

Comment: ps1 to move a VM to a Zone: https://github.com/kpantos/azure-automation/blob/master/powershell/change-vm-zone.ps1